# MYSQL - Get count of specific value inside a query that has a group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the number of times a value shows up in a column but only after it has been group by'd. I'll explain below -

This query gets me these results -

```
select id_seed, id_campaign, id_chat from messages where id_campaign = 140 group by id_chat;
+------------+-------------+----------------------------------------+
| id_seed    | id_campaign | id_chat                                |
+------------+-------------+----------------------------------------+
| 4102593936 |         140 | 0d60b2a4a79938b07ac39b977a96efc4CCC140 |
| 4102593936 |         140 | 1118cb4436f5e5d03f4805d0b9e8bf3eCCC140 |
| 4075174669 |         140 | 12d59be001fc6d795c2da5f9456b41afCCC140 |
| 4102593936 |         140 | 2032e80ca46bca4a5d97f2da92e9f7b1CCC140 |
| 4102593936 |         140 | a6ab87684aa1a90dff7ea61cf618d3f9CCC140 |
| 4075174669 |         140 | ace48ab48c4409e6307a2dc55856ce72CCC140 |
| 4075174669 |         140 | d09d4cf87e5d8b2c3efcfea1fd94f9eaCCC140 |
| 4102593936 |         140 | d2f5fc4c1d7d9d95cfd4846234f6aad3CCC140 |
| 4102593936 |         140 | d5b6712b51878a2f37e7004bc5b57171CCC140 |
+------------+-------------+----------------------------------------+
```

I almost have what I'm looking for here but for some reason it's not adding up together.

```
select distinct count(id_seed) as c, id_seed from messages where id_campaign = 140 group by id_chat, id_seed;
+---+------------+
| c | id_seed    |
+---+------------+
| 1 | 4075174669 |
| 5 | 4102593936 |
| 1 | 4102593936 |
| 2 | 4075174669 |
```

I want to get how many times each value occurs inside column id_seed after the group by has been performed. I'm close and got pretty far but still stuck. Any clues?

Comment: `value shows up` which value?? `after the group by has been performed` I really can't understand this question.

Comment: the id_seed value. you see how in the 2nd query i get what i'm looking for but it's still broken up and not adding together for some reason

Comment: i'm looking for

| c | id_seed         |
----------------------+
| 3 | 4075174669      |
| 6 | 4102593936      |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*),
    id_seed
FROM
    (
        select 
            id_seed
        from 
            messages 
        where 
            id_campaign = 140 
        group by 
            id_chat
    )
GROUP BY
    id_seed
```

Comment: ok, that gives me the total number of records in id_seed. here's a full breakdown of what i'm looking for. maybe this might make more sense? i wish i knew the terminology behind it but i don't :(

Comment: oh now i see. just use subquery :) i updated my answer. Sorry i couldn't get your point

Comment: ok cool. can you please write out an example? that'd be awesome

Comment: no worries on not understanding me. it all makes sense in my head and trying to portray it on here is hard sometimes. thanks for the help so far

Comment: friggin awesome, yea we're good now. thanks so much peter! i have a ways to learn still